# Where is the libOAuth.a source?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, oauth, oauth-provider

Nowadays, I'm working on an iPhone project that is using social connections such as Twitter, Facebook..

When I tried to implement Twitter+OAuth solution into my project some another parts of project such as MySpace is giving error on oAuth implementation. It seems MySpace IOS SDK used old version of oAuthConsumer project.

So, I haven't find libOAuth.a source code. If I find it I will be handle my problem.

How do I find the libOAuth.a static library source ?

Answer (score 2):

try downloading it from `https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/blob/master/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries%20&%20Headers/libOAuth.a?raw=true`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [`this`](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/tree/master/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries%20&%20Headers) what you're looking for? And not only do you have to include it into the project but also make sure you copy into it. Then under `Build Phases`, you will have to add this to `Link Binary to Libraries` section.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Google's new **OAuth 2** library for Mac and iOS](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/) to be helpful.